# Save SQL statement in Memo/Text Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am building a Batch table in an Access database to save operations from a form to be processed after the user clicks the submit button (on the form).

My only concern is that the SQL Statements themselves will have text qualifiers in them.  When i submit the sql statement to be stored in the database i have to wrap the sql string in a text qualifier and i want to make sure that the statement qualifiers will not be escaped when performing a Insert statement into the batch table.

Example:
SQL Statement (operational statement)

```
INSERT INTO tblGrpLoc (gid, txt) VALUES (2, 'Select * From tblInformation')
```

SQL Statement (batch storage)

```
INSERT INTO tblBatch(act, sql) VALUES (0, 'INSERT INTO tblGrpLoc (gid, txt) VALUES (2, 'Select * From tblInformation')')
```

Eventually i would iterate through the Batch table and only execute the field `sql` and update another field to denote its execution but i want to make sure that the `sql` field itself will be homogenous with the sql statement to be executed with no loss of string qualifiers.

### **Edited (2012-08-13 @ 13:42pm CST)**

To give you an idea of how this nesting is being incorporated here is the method:

```
Public Sub BatchAdd(ByRef db As Database, action As BatchAction, sql As String)
    Dim bsql As String
    Dim bact As Integer: bact = CInt(action)
    bsql = SQLInsert("tblBatchTransaction", _
                    "action, txt", _
                    (CStr(bact) & ",'" & sql & "'"))
    db.Execute bsql
End Sub
```

SLQInsert simply builds a SQL Insert statment.  No you can see how i might have a String Qualifier issue arise.

Comment: You can avoid this problem with parameters.

Comment: havent found any GOOD documentation on parameter coding.  everything that i have gone to makes way TOO MANY assumptions.  Last time i dealt with Access was back in 2002, before i transitioned to MSSQL, so my knowledge of Access is out of date.

Comment: If you dislike parameters so much, you can use a recordset and similarly avoid the problem. You are inserting records one at a time, so the speed should not be a problem.

Comment: didnt say i didnt like parameters, just said i havent found any good resource that explain the use of parameters.  End result is iterating through the batch table and executing the stored statements one at a time anyways since Access doesnt allow for true batch processing.

Comment: I am not sure where you are going, but you seem to have moved on from storing the SQL, so `Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", DLookup("SQLText", "sysSQL", _
            "ObjectType='Query' AND ObjectName='AddTable'")):
    qdf.Parameters!txtTableName = TableName`:qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

Comment: the SQL Statements are against the Access Database not a MSSQL database.  Unless im misstaken, all uses of QueryDef's, that i have seen online, where all targeting a MSSQL server and not an Access DB.  I am working on the backend structure but i still need to store series of statements prior to submitting the information to the Access Table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15292/discussion-between-remou-and-goldbishop)

Comment: What I posted is for an Access database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to store your SQL statement in such a way that it can be run as-is.  However, the internal single quotes are getting in the way.  Try replacing the outer single quotes with double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO tblBatch(act, sql) VALUES (0, "INSERT INTO tblGrpLoc (gid, txt) VALUES (2, 'Select * From tblInformation')")
```

Comment: Its not really them getting in the way, i can just fore-see the problem eventually rearing its head and want to get some logic to mitigate the problem from happening.

Comment: @GoldBishop Is the sql from a query or from VBA?